# how to pass jwt from swift client to node.js server

Tags: node.js, swift, websocket

I want to pass jwt from swift client to node.js websocket server for authentication. I have implemented native websocket client in swift.
i found some solution for node.js client in which they are doing like this-

```
WebSocket = require 'ws'
ws = new WebSocket 'ws://localhost:8000',{
    headers : {
        token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiaW9zdHJlYW1lciJ9.oNx-4e9hldyATpdPZghd_sjX8DhTkQFVDBxIhKh4MC4"
    }
}
```

so how can i do this thing on swift client i tried to pass like above in swift too but gave me errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer its pretty simple i can't put the whole code but you guys and understand with this-

```
var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask!
var url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8000")!)

url.addValue("Your_Jwt_Token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: url)
```

or if you want to pass `jwt_Token` through protocol then you can do like this-

```
webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8000")!, protocols: ["Your_Jwt_Token"])
```

The above results in the following headers-

```
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: "Your_jwt_Token"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream) if you are looking for a library to use WebSockets in iOS.

You can then add the headers in the `URLRequest` itself:

(From the example on the library page)

```swift
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!)

/// YOU WANT THIS
request.addValue("TOKEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
/// YOU WANT THIS

request.timeoutInterval = 5
socket = WebSocket(request: request)
socket.delegate = self
socket.connect()
```

I would recommend sending the token in the `Authorization` header as mentioned in the example because it is a standard practice. But if you want to send it as your Node.js example, replace `Authorization` with `token`.

And `TOKEN` with the token you want to send.

**Edit**
Even if you are not using this library, the process is similar.